# How do I choose between "while" and "whilst"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, conjunctions

When should *whilst* be used instead of *while*?

For example, should I use the first or the second sentence?

> They don't do this whilst they do that.
>   They don't do this while they do that.

Which would be correct?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe while and whilst are interchangeable, but whilst is more archaic and adds a nice flavoring to the sentence.

That being said, "whilst" doesn't seem to come up so often in the middle of a sentence as you had it there, so I would use "while" in that case, even though both are grammatically correct. Whilst seems more apt to be put at the beginnings of sentences, e.g.

> Whilst going about my merry way I chanced upon a vagabond. Taking this serendipitous opportunity to satiate my bloodlust I decapitated him with a fork.

Comment: while reading your answer claidiu with interest, i must add that whilst i agreed per se i much prefer the latter form, being as you say prettier on the page, on the tongue and in the minds eye.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure that *while* has been around longer, and *whilst* was a derivative form.

Answer (score 13):

The two words 'while' and 'whilst' mean the same thing. They could be considered alternate pronunciations of the same word, similar to among/amongst or further/farther. ['While' came first](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=while), and then ['whilst' was derived from it](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=whilst&allowed_in_frame=0).

But they are not used with the same frequency and they give different 'feels'. 'While' is [much more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=while%2C+whilst&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) (from Google nGrams)

[image]

'Whilst' sounds archaic, affected, or hyperacademic (which means no one in academia uses it).

To Americans, 'whilst' sounds British, but at least in print, there is very little difference in the frequencies of the two words between AmE and BrE (via Google nGrams)

In the end, it is correct grammar to use them interchangeably, but it is bad style...uh sorry, not the current fashion to use 'whilst'. No one (at least not in formal writing, like for newspapers or academic writing) uses 'whilst' anymore. It may be common and accepted in certain varieties of English (say Indian English) but is very jarring in standard English.

However, in the 18th century the two were on more equal terms. The classic study of text analysis by [Mosteller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Mosteller#Contributions_to_statistics) and Wallace to help discover the authorship of the Federalist papers was based primarily on the use of differentiating pairs like this.

Comment: I would disagree that _whilst_ is “very jarring in standard English”. It is definitely less common, and I can’t think of any context where I would personally be more likely to use _whilst_ than _while_; but if I heard someone use it, I would not find it jarring at all. I doubt I’d even really notice. Also, _further_ and _farther_ are not completely interchangeable: _farther_ is very unusual (I would say ungrammatical) in most abstract and metaphorical uses, where only _further_ is used.

Comment: Thanks for the n-gram. An upvote for the extra level of research involved.

Answer (score 2):

"Whilst" and "while" are interchangeable. The difference between the two is "whilst" is British English and "while" is American English.

Comment: N.B. In British English, both are used (and they're essentially interchangeable). Similar to "among"/"amongst".

Answer (score 2):

The unobstructed and clearest path to perfect communication is to write and say what is least bothersome. This is a good example. When I encounter "whilst", I find it jarring.  It immediately makes me wonder whether the writer is foolishly groping to sound important. My advice is to write it as you would say it.  And if you would normally say "while", then for heaven's sake, don't write that other officious, antiquated word of the same meaning.

Comment: 'The unobstructed and clearest path to perfect communication is to write and say what is least bothersome.' But isn't OP asking precisely that, _what most people find least bothersome_? Unsupported answers come across as, and may just be, personal preference rather than idiomatic choices.

Answer (score 1):

I would typically use `whilst` to emphasize the targeted time period; as if that period of time was very important to your expression.

For instance, your boss complains to you for having been out sick for a few days **while** you were still capable to and actively help through whatever means available **whilst** being sick.

If you had only used `while`, then your sentence would lack that "flavor" that another poster mentioned.  It doesn't sound as direct, and furthermore, it would sound repetitive to use `while` twice in one sentence.