# Difference between "while" and "whilst"

Tags: expressions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct usage of “while” and “whilst”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16319/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-while-and-whilst)

In terms of construction of sentences, can the two words *while* and *whilst* be used interchangeably?

Comment: For the first word, do you mean 'while' or 'whiles'? I have never seen 'whiles' before. If 'whiles' do you have a reference where you've seen this used?

Comment: @Mitch - I'm wondering if he didn't mean "wiles" (which is of course a different word entirely).

Comment: also among/amongst

Comment: @Mitch Whiles is a word, e.g "He whiles away the day in [chat]"

Comment: @Matt: Oh right...then no answer so far accounts for that (but then neither does the OP give enough context to realize that).

Comment: Let me chew on this for a whilst.

Comment: This is no longer the same question. I say, roll back the edit. Esp. because the new version is a duplicate.

Comment: @Kris: I've [raised the issue in meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2597/dodgy-duplicate-closure)

Comment: @Matt: That's a verb usage. But there's also ["You do this whiles I do that"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1BfmvswJHDYC&pg=PA179&lpg=PA179&dq=%22whiles+I+make%22&source=bl&ots=VoKCCE5YGT&sig=YkhgldjuAaNqM8ec5y8awv2Mxwo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=q7qZT9nECMn48QOIqvTlBQ&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22whiles%20I%20make%22&f=false) - which may or may not be ignorant failure to use the word **whilst**. All I know is I've heard people use that construction, enunciating it as **while əz** (neutral vowel giving the word effectively *two* syllables).

Comment: Would the question mean anything different without the words “terms of”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Garner in Modern American Usage has a good entry on this. He says:

> *whilst*, though correct BrE, is virtually obsolete in AmE and reeks of
>   pretension in the work of American writer.
>   [...] 
>   Like its sibiling *while*, it may be used for although or whereas. But again, this isn't good usage in AmE.

As NOAD say *whiles* is archaic form of *while*.

So, *whiles* and *whilst* might be interchangeable, but with the above warnings.

Answer (score 3):

The entry at [World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-whi2.htm) says that *while* and *whilst* are forms of the same word. He notes:

> Both *while* and *whilst* are ancient, though *while* is older. There’s no difference in meaning between them. For reasons that aren’t clear, ***whilst* has survived in British English but has died out in the US.** However, in Britain it is considered to be a more formal and literary word than its counterpart.

How did it come to be this way? Like *amid* and *amidst*, he adds:

> In both cases, the form ending in -st actually contains the -s of the genitive ending (which we still have today, though usually written as ’s, of course). In Middle English, this was often added to words used as adverbs (as *while* became *whiles*, which often turned up in the compound adverbs *somewhiles* and *otherwhiles*). What seems to have happened is that a -t was later added in the south of England through confusion with the superlative ending -st (as in *gentlest*).

So you can use them interchangeably, but note that *whilst* reads as more formal. In American English, it appears extremely rarely so be aware of the audience you're addressing when you make this choice.

Comment: The word *whilst* is so extinct in American English that if you have Americans read aloud a sentence containing the word, they’ll often mispronounce it, using the /ɪ/ of *sit* instead of the /aɪ/ of *wise*. They just don’t hear it often enough.

Comment: @tchrist I've seen it a few times (I only know Am. E), but it might have been from really old texts.

Comment: *Whilst* is current in UK English, but archaic in American English. I would say that *amidst* isn’t quite defunct in American English, whereas *amongst* is getting there, at least in some publications. You’ll also see some US publications banishing the final *s* on words like *towards*, even though in fact many American speakers use that form almost exclusively.

Comment: Does it mean that a word "almost" will become "almo" at some point in the distant future? :)