# When should I use "while" and when should I use "whilst"?

Tags: word-choice

I was curious as to the correct uses of the words "whilst" and "while". In what context should I use them?

Comment: @TrevorD, I'm a native speaker and I don't know the answer.

Comment: @TrevorD: This is pretty ELU. Do you really think it is so elementary?

Comment: Use *while* in the present day. Use *whilst* in the 17th century.

Comment: @Mitch *et al*.  OK. Deleted comments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct usage of "while" and "whilst"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16319/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-while-and-whilst). Also related: [When did “while” and “whilst” become interchangeable?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6/when-did-while-and-whilst-become-interchangeable)

Answer (score 0):

[ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/whilst) shows

> **whilst** *conjunction & adverb*
>   while

OED shows

> **whilst** *adv.* and *conj.* (and *prep.*)
>   **2. a.** *conj.* = while
>   **3.** *transf.* = while
>   **4.** *conj.* Till, until: =while

It appears not to matter which you choose — although as everything points back to *while,* that would be the word most people would use.

[A Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=while+-+while_NOUN%2Cwhilst&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows that *while* has consistently been more popular than *whilst* since 1700, **and** the latter has declined recently. [Note that *while* excludes the noun. The erratic nature of the 17th century is because of the paucity of published data, but the results appear to be far closer then than now.]

[image: NGram]

Comment: Unless you are in the US, in which case use *while*. *Whilst* would be considered archaic or simply strange.

Comment: @bib You're right. I've made that a bit more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

"Whilst" is an old fashioned usage according to Americans and the British. They prefer while. Both have the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst is relatively common in British English, in my experience, but be aware in that in the North of England (particularly North Yorkshire), "while" can be used to mean "until".

For example, "I waited while 4 o'clock for a bus"; "I'm on holiday while Thursday". See [here](http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.co.uk/2006/06/whilst.html) for further discussion